# ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(546, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I was just trying out for DataPreprocessing where I frequently get this error.Can anyone explain me what is wrong in this particular code for the given dataset?

Thanks in advance!

```
# STEP 1: IMPORTING THE LIBARIES

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# STEP 2: IMPORTING THE DATASET
dataset = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/Avik-Jain/100-Days-Of-ML-Code/blob/master/datasets/Data.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values  
Y = dataset.iloc[:,1:3].values

# STEP 3: HANDLING THE MISSING VALUES
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN",strategy = "mean",axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[ : , 1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3]) 

# STEP 4: ENCODING CATEGPRICAL DATA
from sklearn.preprocessing import LaberEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()  # Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
X[ : , 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[ : , 0]) # All the rows and first columns

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y =  labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)

# Step 5: Splitting the datasets into training sets and Test sets

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( X , Y , test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Step 6: Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.fit_transform(X_test)
```

Returns Error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(546, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Comment: Can you `print()` your `x` and `y` variables? There may be a mismatch in dimensionality.

Comment: Can you also post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link in this line

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/Avik-Jain/100-Days-Of-ML-Code/blob/master/datasets/Data.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

is wrong.

The current link returns the webpage on github where this csv is shown, but not the actual csv data. So whatever data is present in `dataset` is invalid.

Change that to:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Avik-Jain/100-Days-Of-ML-Code/master/datasets/Data.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Other than that, there is a spelling mistake in `LabelEncoder` import.

Now even if you correct these, there will still be errors, because of

```
Y =  labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```

LabelEncoder only accepts a single column array as input, but your current `Y` will be of 2 columns due to

```
Y = dataset.iloc[:,1:3].values
```

Please explain more clearly what do you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it worked out.Actually I am just a newbie to MachineLearning and I started the 100 days of ml code.the first one was DataPreprocessing and I got stuck there but after your suggestion the error is solved!