# Django with machine leaing gives this error Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required

Tags: django, python-3.x, machine-learning, heroku, numpy-ndarray

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import questions
from .serializers import approvalSerializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import os
from avasyu import settings
import pickle
import requests
import numpy as np
from django.core.cache import cache
# Create your views here.

data = []


def landing_views(request):
    return render(request, "avasyuapp/landing.html")


def ques_views(request):
    cache.clear()
    return render(request, "avasyuapp/ques.html")


def store_db(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ans1 = request.POST["answer1"]
        ans2 = request.POST["answer2"]
        ans3 = request.POST["answer3"]
        ans4 = request.POST["answer4"]
        ans5 = request.POST["answer5"]
        ans6 = request.POST["answer6"]
        ans7 = request.POST["answer7"]
        ans8 = request.POST["answer8"]
        ans9 = request.POST["answer9"]

        data.append(ans1)
        data.append(ans2)
        data.append(ans3)
        data.append(ans4)
        data.append(ans5)
        data.append(ans6)

        o1 = questions(
            ques='Have you motivated yourself to become a good communicator?', ans=ans1)
        o1.save()

        o2 = questions(
            ques='Can you speak in front of group without any nervousness?', ans=ans2)
        o2.save()

        o3 = questions(
            ques='Can you justify you as a good communicator?', ans=ans3)
        o3.save()

        o4 = questions(
            ques='Are you really happy to make communication as your future passion?', ans=ans4)
        o4.save()

        o5 = questions(
            ques='Is your english vocabulary and comprehension strong?', ans=ans5)
        o5.save()

        o6 = questions(ques='Are you good at grammar?', ans=ans6)
        o6.save()

        o7 = questions(
            ques='Have you achieved anything till date as a good communicator ?', ans=ans7)
        o7.save()

        o8 = questions(
            ques='Are you a good listener,good reader and are you clear in your communication when communicating with others ?', ans=ans8)
        o8.save()

        o9 = questions(ques='Are you spending any time on reading ?', ans=ans9)
        o9.save()

        print("Stored in DB..")
        # print(data)
        cache.clear()
        return render(request, 'avasyuapp/result.html')

    else:
        return redirect('ques/')


class ApprovalsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = questions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = approvalSerializers


answer = []


def input_con(ans):

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if ans[i] == 'Yes':
            answer.insert(i, 3)
        elif ans[i] == 'Partially Yes':
            answer.insert(i, 2)
        elif ans[i] == 'Partially No':
            answer.insert(i, 1)
        else:
            answer.insert(i, 0)
    return answer


def output_con(classifier):
    if classifier == 3:
        result = 'Yes'
    elif classifier == 2:
        result = 'Partially Yes'
    elif classifier == 1:
        result = 'Partially No'
    else:
        result = 'No'
    return result


@api_view(["POST"])
def approvereject(request):
    files = os.path.join(settings.MODELS, 'classifierfinal.pkl')
    with open(files, 'rb') as file:
        classifier = pickle.load(file)
    #classifier = joblib.load(file)

    converted_data = input_con(data)
    # print(data)
    output = classifier.predict([converted_data])
    print(output)
    dis_out = output_con(output)
    print(dis_out)
    cache.clear()
    return render(request, 'avasyuapp/output.html', {'output': dis_out})
```

**Initially when i push the code to the repo i get the expected output but when i reload the application i get either 0 features or the features gets double after each run. After i reload the application i get this error i need to push it to the heroku again again to get the output. how can i clear the buffer after each submit and stop getting this 0 features error.**

```
ValueError at /output/
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://avasyu.herokuapp.com/output/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array, line 594
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 12 Mar 2020 19:45:41 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I know is that Django is not a Machine Learning framework, so I am not sure what you mean by ML here.

I can't really follow what your code is doing but

> Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.

Appears to come from Scikit Learn, which must be the ML framework you are using? this question addresses that error
[ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(546, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050057/valueerror-found-array-with-0-features-shape-546-0-while-a-minimum-of-1)