# ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(16, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I was just trying to learn about machine learning, and I tried this script but I got an error. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with this particular code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
dataset = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, :1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                               y,
                                               test_size = 0.2,
                                               random_state = 0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()     
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) #this line 15 generates the error message
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(dataku.BiayaPromo, dataku.NilaiPenjualan)
plt.xlabel("Biaya Promosi")
plt.ylabel("Nilai Penjualan")
plt.title("Grafik Nilai Penjualan VS Biaya Promosi")
plt.show()
```

return eror :
the eror is in line 15

```
    ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(16, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Comment: Hi, which line causes the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(546, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050057/valueerror-found-array-with-0-features-shape-546-0-while-a-minimum-of-1)

Comment: @aaossa the eror was at line 15 idk why

Comment: @Mr.T the data is only 2 tables and 21 rows of numbers that I scrambled

Comment: @Mr.T actually i just want to try meachine learning but it was an error idk why

Comment: Can you provide the values for `X_train.shape` and `y_train.shape`? The error states that your `X_train` has 0 columns, so I suggest printing `X,shape` and/or `X` too right after `X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values` and see if the output matches your expectations